# Text is not wrapping onto next line - specifically in IE

Tags: css

Please see the picture below:

[image]

It is a cell in a table - I have commented out the text.  Notice the text overflows.  This happens in IE (11) only i.e. all the other browsers e.g. Chrome; Firefox; Edge etc simply move the text to the next line.  How do I facilitate line wrapping for IE.  So far I have tried this css, which has no effect:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: can you try this `white-space:pre-line`

Comment: @Rayees AC, that pushes the entire line down one line (with the same problem).  How do I wrap the text?

Comment: Can you add html code make to easy to find the solution? thanks :)

Comment: Is the text *one* long word or are there several words with regular spaces between them?

Comment: Removing: align-items: center; seemed to fix the IE specific issue (I am using Flexbox).